# Parse doesn't create users anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, parse-platform

Just started to code with parse. I made a simpel user signup app and it worked to sign up new users a couple of times. After a couple of users singed up it stopped working, i doesn't sign up any new users. Can't seem to figure out what the problem is.
This is the code

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, "my app-id", "my client-key");

ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername("my name");
user.setPassword("my pass");
user.setEmail("email@example.com");

// other fields can be set just like with ParseObject
user.put("phone", "650-253-0000");

user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
public void done(ParseException e) {
if (e == null) {
  // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
} else {
  // Sign up didn't succeed. Look at the ParseException
  // to figure out what went wrong
   }
  }
});
```

Comment: Figure out debug strategy and avoid duplicate values on crit fields like email

Comment: What Robert said. If you're actually using the above code, it's only going to work the first time. Otherwise, you're going to be receiving an error saying duplicate username or e-mail.

Comment: i tried to change the user information multiple times but it didn't work either. Also deleted the users that was stored to be sure it wasn't because of user duplication, didn't work either

Comment: Try to put ParseException into your logcat to see what is the error. `e.printStackTrace()`